# Google maps API with OpenUI5 CORS error

Tags: google-maps, cors, sapui5, geocoding

I was trying to create an app that displays user address based on his coordinates with Google Maps API the code is working fine inside Eclipse IDE.

But when I host it on IIS I receive the following error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=30.0043704,31.176554&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCEZN8UB34nbx3D-17xk1J-DRnNCF_kjm4.
>   Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

And my code is below

```
var position = null;
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(aPosition) {
            position = aPosition;
            jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");
            $.sap.log.error("LAT:" + position.coords.latitude + " LON:" + position.coords.longitude);
            var oGeoModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var aData = jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude +
                            "&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCEZN8UB34nbx3D-17xk1J-DRnNCF_kjm4",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    oGeoModel.setData({
                        modelData: data
                    });
                    //alert("success to post");
                    myView.byId("txtVendCountry").setValue(oGeoModel.getProperty("/modelData/results/4/formatted_address"));
                    myView.byId("txtVendRegion").setValue(oGeoModel.getProperty("/modelData/results/2/formatted_address"));
                    myView.byId("txtVendorAddress").setValue(oGeoModel.getProperty("/modelData/results/0/formatted_address"));
                    console.log(oGeoModel);
                }
            });
            console.log(oGeoModel);
        });
    } else {
        sap.m.MessageToast.show("Sorry, your browser does not support geolocation services.");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error log shows that issue is with Content-Type. Try the method below. It is fairly simple.

```
var url =  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latLang=" --your lat lang" + "&sensor=false&----yourAPIKey4---&callback=getJSON";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                //set data to model here
            });
```